# What does the notation $\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ p)$ mean?

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand the Fermat theory : 
$a^{p-1} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ p)$

I know that $a\ (\text{mod}\ p)$ gives the remainder of division of $a$ by $p$. So what is $\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ p)$?

Thank you.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ means that dividing $a^{p-1}$ by $p$ leaves a remainder of $1$.  Or equivalently it means that $p$ divides $a^{p-1}-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a\equiv b\pmod p$$ means that

> $a-b$ is a multiple of $p$,

or equivalently that

> the remainder of dividing $a$ by $p$ is the same as the remainder of dividing $b$ by $p$.

This notation is nearly the first topic discussed in [the Wikipedia article on modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation).  Have you tried reading that?

Comment: No, I'm going to read it now. Thank you that is really helpful